# What does \\x80-\\xFF refer to?

Tags: php, regex

In the process of looking for solutions to help sanitise some output, I came across code that does the following.

```
preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9-~+_.?#=!&;,/:%@$\|*\'()\\x80-\\xff]|i', '', $some_url)
```

Now, I think it's basically trying to remove anything other than the above mentioned characters. But doesn't `\\x80-\\xff` refer to some form of non-printable ascii characters ? If so, why would the code possibly be trying NOT to remove them ?

Any indications/pointers/help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, all the answers given so far lead me in the right direction and allowed me to find the following in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

> After \x, up to two hexadecimal digits are read (letters can be in
>   upper or lower case). In UTF-8 mode, \x{...} is allowed, where the
>   contents of the braces is a string of hexadecimal digits. It is
>   interpreted as a UTF-8 character whose code number is the given
>   hexadecimal number. The original hexadecimal escape sequence, \xhh,
>   matches a two-byte UTF-8 character if the value is greater than 127.

So, as a summary :-

i) '\x' allows for a hexadecimal escape sequence, after which, up to two hexadecimal digits are read

ii) '\xhh' the two 'hh' letters can be in upper or lower case

iii) '\xhh' specifies a code-point in the range 0-FF

iv) '\x80-\xFF' refers to a character range outside ASCII

Answer (score 5):

`x80`-`xFF` are non-ASCII character ranges. They're still printable, both in Latin-1, or encode higher code points for UTF-8.

Using `\\x80` over `\x80` is slightly more correct. The backslash escapes itself in strings. In single quoted strings too, albeit it's effectively irrelevant there.

In double quoted strings however using just `\x80` would be interpreted by PHP, whereas `\\x80` would be seen and interpreted by the regex engine.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I understand the first part of your answer. But ...

"In double quoted strings however using just \x80 would be interpreted by PHP, whereas \\x80 would be seen and interpreted by the regex engine."

... lost me. Besides, shouldn't the double backslash end up escaping the backslash itself, forcing it to be treated as a separate character... and leaving x80 and xFF to be treated individually without any backslashes ?

Comment: After re-reading the answer, I would also like to ask whether '|x80 - xFF|i' without any backslashes is valid syntax to mean the same thing as the above.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Read up on [PHP strings](http://php.net/string#language.types.string.syntax.double) regarding the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use double backslash in a pattern with PHP, however even if you use it, it is ignored and read as an escape (like a simple backslash).

One exception, if you use the heredoc or nowdoc syntax to enclose the pattern, a double backslash is seen as a literal backslash.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 byte sequences for ASCII characters is 1 byte like `0xxxxxxx` so it matches `\x00-\x7f`.

If a character is not ASCII  means it has more than 1 byte and in that case bytes will be described with the leading `1`

Part of the table from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding)

```
num of bytes
    1           0xxxxxxx
    2           110xxxxx    10xxxxxx    
    3           1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    
    4           11110xxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

so `\x80-\xff` matches `1xxxxxxx` bytes from multibyte characters so basically non-ASCII characters.